# Prevent child elements overflowing max-height of parent

Tags: css, html, layout

I'm trying to produce a layout where I have a div with a percentage height of the body.  In addition, I also want to limit this height using `max-height`.

Inside the parent, I want to create some columns that have further sub-elements, all of which fit within the height (or max-height) of the parent.

Please see this example: http://jsfiddle.net/k6rfr/2/

The problem is that the child elements (with a height of 50% each), match the `height` of the parent and not the `max-height`.

Is there any way to make the child elements match the `max-height` instead of the `height`?

Comment: Have you tried adding `overflow: auto` to the parent container?

Comment: Yea, tried this but it just adds scrollbars - not exactly the look I'm going for! - http://jsfiddle.net/ZxAdf/1/

Answer (score 1):

Though this is not exactly what you might need, it solves your problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/k6rfr/3/

I placed the max-height directy in the child-elements omiting the second wrapper element. The problem you have here is that you have to define the height in two different places.

Comment: Yea, I was hoping it wouldn't be necessary to define the additional max-heights but it's looking as though it's my only option..

Comment: @Tom perhaps this is a good point to start with SASS or LESS. THen you can work with variables and never have such problems again;)

Comment: Certainly seems easier than waiting for browser rendering to make sense!

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is that a given block "outer" height of 60% may not correspond to what you wrote after 300px. It's not correct. If you remove a specified percentage of the height, the blocks would fall into place. Or enter the correct proportion height and max-height.